# How to send SMS from PC to mobile using Java bluetooth OBEX (bluecove api)?

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluecove

I read the `MAP SPEC` in order to send a x-bt/message from my `PC` to my mobile, I am using `JAVA blucove API`.

I was able to connect over `OBEX protocol` successful but I had no return from mobile phone and the message was not send.

My OBEX Header:

```
            HeaderSet hsOperation = clientSession.createHeaderSet();
            hsOperation.setHeader(HeaderSet.TYPE, "x-bt/message");
            hsOperation.setHeader(HeaderSet.LENGTH,new Long(sMessage.length()));
            hsOperation.setHeader(HeaderSet.NAME, "TELECOM/MSG/OUTBOX");
```

My bMessage and OutputStream:

```
private final static String CRLF = "\r\n";

static String sMessage = "BEGIN:BMSG"+CRLF
        + "VERSION:1.0"+CRLF
        + "STATUS:UNREAD"+CRLF
        + "TYPE:SMS_GSM"+CRLF
        + " FOLDER:TELECOM/MSG/OUTBOX"+CRLF
        + "BEGIN:VCARD"+CRLF
        + "    VERSION:2.1"+CRLF
        + "    N:Souza,Ricardo"+CRLF
        + "    TEL:+5511666666666"+CRLF
        + "END:VCARD"+CRLF
        + "BEGIN:BENV"+CRLF
        + "    BEGIN:VCARD"+CRLF
        + "        VERSION:2.1"+CRLF
        + "        N:Souza,Ricardo"+CRLF
        + "        TEL:+5511666666666"+CRLF
        + "    END:VCARD"+CRLF
        + "    BEGIN:BBODY"+CRLF
        + "        ENCODING:G-7BIT"+CRLF
        + "        LENGTH:47"+CRLF
        + "        BEGIN:MSG"+CRLF
        + "            This is a short message"+CRLF
        + "        END:MSG"+CRLF
        + "    END:BBODY"+CRLF
        + "END:BENV"+CRLF
        + "END:BMSG"+CRLF; 

    OutputStream os = putOperation.openOutputStream();
    os.write(sMessage.getBytes());
    os.close();
```

Could someone help me to visualize what is wrong? Please, if someone already worked with `Java OBEX` in order to send `SMS` (MAP stack) from PC to mobile. ( like `carkits handsfree`).

Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the whitespace: replace the lines like

```
...
+ "    VERSION:2.1"+CRLF
...
```

by

```
...
+ "VERSION:2.1"+CRLF
...
```

Furthermore the message is expected in 7bit encoding, but in the code above just an ASCII string is provided.
E.g. the following block contains the text "Let's go fishing!"

```
...
"BEGIN:BBODY\r\n" +
    "ENCODING:G-7BIT\r\n" +
    "LENGTH:82\r\n" +
    "BEGIN:MSG\r\n" + /*Length 11 */
        "0001000E8100949821436587000011CC32FD34079DDF20737A8E4EBBCF21\r\n" + /* Length 62 */
    "END:MSG\r\n" + /* Length 9 */
"END:BBODY\r\n" +
 ...
```

this example is copied from the test suite https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/